# Switch “goes to sleep” … sometimes

Tags: switching

**tl;dr:** a switch will pass traffic between 2 segments for a while, but then 
"goes to sleep"(?) for 1 of the two directions on that data path. Packets from 1 segment will wake it up, but not from the other segment. Note: that this happens with multiple different switches, not just one.

I thought I knew how to toubleshoot network problems, but this one has me stumped.

Master router is connected by CAT5e to switches throughout the house.
It's a large house so there are several switches, plus a few old
routers acting as WiFi Access Points (WAP) / switches to help serve the
poor-reception WiFi spots.  Only the Master router runs a DHCP server,
the others do not.

One switch, in the attic, has 3 active ports (A-C), connected as follows:

```
A->Master router
B->Office switch
    B.1->file server
    B.2->desktop
    B.3->printer
C->Kids' room WAP / switch
    C.wifi.1->kid's computer
    C.2->WAP in kitchen
        C.2.wifi.1->tablet
    C.3->tivo
```

Initially all machines can talk to all other machines. After a period of
time, measured in anything from a few minutes to several hours, the switch
in the attic will no longer pass traffic from B to C. On the other hand,
if any machine anywhere on the C segment does *anything* (e.g. ping 8.8.8.8),
then suddenly traffic will start flowing B->C, at least for a while. B can
always talk to the A segment, and A can converse with C without changing the
current state of the B->C anomaly.

Things tried:

- We have swapped the attic switch with 5(!) different switches from
  different manufacturers and all manifest the problem. That's right,
  **it is a near certainty that *the attic switch* is not the problem!(!!, etc.)**
- We used a long cable to connect the C segment directly to a port on the
  Master and the problem does not manifest.

Current Kludge:

- Our current kludge is to have a cron job on B.1 (running Ubuntu
  14.04) ping C (the WAP itself) every 10 minutes. This seems to be enough to keep the
  intermediate switch "awake", but it is deeply unsatisfying to not
  know the true cause of the problem.

**Update**:

This started manifesting about 3 months ago. No known modifications to the network, and no known work by tradespeople anywhere near the cables.

The C WAP is an old Linksys router with DHCP turned off, and no cable connected to the "Internet" jack. It has a static IP on the LAN. I'm not sure about the make/model of the WAP in the kitchen. (This is at a friend's house.)

Comment: Has this always happened for the entirety of the network? Or is this something that just started happening? The fact that the stalling happens, but traffic resumes when any device on segment C does anything makes my first guess to be some problem with ARP maybe?
What kind of WAP is being used for segment C?

Comment: I answered 2 of your questions in the Update above. As to it being ARP related ... I don't see how that would happen (which also applies to this whole mess). Remember, this has been tested with multiple different switches and **they all do the same thing!** It's almost like there is an unseen 3rd party (maybe a net-savvy cockroach?) in the wall that is 'eating' network state.

Comment: You say you've only swapped the same switch several times though. You never mentioned replacing the WAP/switch in segment C where the problem seems to be consistently losing communication, or even possibly the switch on port B. Given the reliability of some home level WAP's I would first start with the WAP at C.

Comment: AH! I *totally* missed that as the possible / probable failure point. Thank you!

Comment: Ha! That's kind of funny. Hopefully looking into one of those devices leads to a solution. Good luck, and of course feel free to update the question with more info if you still run into roadblocks.